# XGBoost: Feature Names Mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost

I'm struggling big-time to get my XGBoost model to predict an article's engagement time from its text.  First, I get a dataframe representing the features I extracted from the article like this:

```
article_features = pd.concat([tfidf_df, numeric_df_normalized], axis=1)
```

I then train my model and get the relevant correct columns (features):

```
with open('correct_columns') as fp:
        correct_columns = pickle.load(fp)
```

Then I go through all of the required features and set them to `0.0` if they're not already in `article_features`:

```
for col in correct_columns:
        if col not in article_features.columns:
            article_features[col] = 0.0
```

Finally, I delete features that were extracted from this article that don't exist in the training data:

```
for col in article_features:
    if col not in correct_columns:
        del article_features[col]
```

So now `article_features` has the correct number of features.  I try to run:

```
model.predict(article_features)
```

And I get:

```
ValueError: feature_names mismatch:...
```

So I Google around and try converting my dataframe to :

```
model.predict(article_features.as_matrix())
```

But I get the same error.

I was then worried about order of columns in `article_features` not being the same as `correct_columns` so I did:

```
article_features.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

But got the same error.

Any idea how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: How have you trained the `model`? I mean which features were used in that? Exactly those features should be present during predicting or else it would not make any sense.

Answer (score 4):

The problem occurs due to `DMatrix..num_col()` only returning the amount of non-zero columns in a sparse matrix. Hence, if both train & test data have the same amount of non-zero columns, everything works fine. Otherwise, you end up with different feature names lists. There're currently three solutions to work around this problem:

1. realign the columns names of the train dataframe and test dataframe using

   ```
   test_df = test_df[train_df.columns]
   ```
2. save the model first and then load the model
3. change the test data into array before feeding into the model:

   ```
   use test_df.values
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   test_df
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the data which you use to fit the model to contains exactly the same features as the data you used to train the model.

> Finally, I delete features that were extracted from this article that don't 
>      exist in the training data:
>   ....
>   So now article_features has the correct number of features. ....

What about the features that are present in the data you use to fit the model on but not in the data you used for training?